# Cell width in display: table

Tags: html, css, position, border, css-tables

I create card using `display: table` layouting. This is my attempt so far:

```css
.panel-bg {
  background-color: #F8F8F8; 
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 24px 0;
}

.panel {
  width: calc(100%-32px);
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 6px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0 16px;
}

.panel-title-row {
  display: table-row;
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #c4c4c4;
}

.panel-title {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 80%;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #0099ff;
  padding: 24px;
}

.panel-action {
  text-align: right;
  width: 20%;
  display: table-cell;
}

.panel-action li {
  margin-left: 16px;
}

.panel-action li:last-child {
  margin-left: 32px; 
}

.col-1,
.col-2,
.col-3 {
  width: 33.33%; 
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 24px;
}

.panel-data {
  margin-top: 16px; 
}

.panel-data-label {
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.panel-data-value {
  font-size: 13px; 
  margin-top: 8px;
}

.panel-content {
  display: table-row;
  width: 100%;
}

.panel-data-vertical {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

.panel-data-vertical .panel-data-label,
.panel-data-vertical .panel-data-value {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 50%;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.11/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-p2jx59pefphTFIpeqCcISO9MdVfIm4pNnsL08A6v5vaQc4owkQqxMV8kg4Yvhaw/" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,400i,700,700i" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="panel-bg">

<div class="panel">
  <div class="panel-title-row">
    <div class="panel-title">
      Members
    </div>
    <ul class="panel-action">
      <li><i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i></li>
      <li><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></li>
      <li><i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-content">
    <div class="col-1">
      <div class="panel-data panel-data-horizontal">
        <div class="panel-data-label">
          Effective Date
        </div>
        <div class="panel-data-value">
          1 Jan 2018
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-data panel-data-vertical">
        <div class="panel-data-label">
          Employment Type
        </div>
        <div class="panel-data-value">
          Permanent
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-data panel-data-vertical">
        <div class="panel-data-label">
          Job Level
        </div>
        <div class="panel-data-value">
          Staff
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-data panel-data-vertical">
        <div class="panel-data-label">
          Job Title
        </div>
        <div class="panel-data-value">
          All
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-2">
      
    </div>
    <div class="col-3">
      
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
  
</div>
```

My problems are:

1. I want to put `border-bottom` to the `panel-title-row` but it doesn't show. I want to make the border with the padding (about 24 px) to the left and right but whenever i put padding properties or the `border-bottom` to the row or its children it seems like doesn't work.
2. `panel-title-row` 's children doesn't fill their parent's width to 100% eventhough I set 80% and 20% to each child. When I change the percentage, it affect the `col-1` that doesn't belong to the row.
3. I create another `table-row` below the `panel-title` (named `panel-content`) and I want to divide it to 3 columns with the same width (named `col-1`, `col-2`, and `col-3`) but the `width: 33.33%` doesn't work.

This is what I want to achieve, with emphasis on the space between the card and the line.

[image]

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this may help you, do you want it to be done only using table?

```css
.panel-bg {
  background-color: #F8F8F8; 
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 24px 0;
}

.panel {
  width: calc(100%-32px);
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 6px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0 16px;
padding:25px;
}

.panel-title-row {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #c4c4c4;
}

.panel-title {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 78%;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #0099ff;
  padding: 0;
}

.panel-action {
  text-align: right;
  width: 20%;
  display: inline-block;
padding:0px 5px 15px 0;
margin:0;
}

.panel-action li {
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.panel-action li:last-child {
  margin-left: 29px; 
}

.col-1,
.col-2,
.col-3 {
  width: 33.33%; 
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 5px 0px 20px 0px;
}

.panel-data {
  margin-top: 16px; 
}

.panel-data-label {
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.panel-data-value {
  font-size: 13px; 
  margin-top: 8px;
}

.panel-content {
  display: table-row;
  width: 100%;
}

.panel-data-vertical {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

.panel-data-vertical .panel-data-label,
.panel-data-vertical .panel-data-value {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 50%;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.11/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-p2jx59pefphTFIpeqCcISO9MdVfIm4pNnsL08A6v5vaQc4owkQqxMV8kg4Yvhaw/" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,400i,700,700i" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="panel-bg">

<div class="panel">
  <div class="panel-title-row">
    <div class="panel-title">
      Members
    </div>
    <ul class="panel-action">
      <li><i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i></li>
      <li><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></li>
      <li><i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-content">
    <div class="col-1">
      <div class="panel-data panel-data-horizontal">
        <div class="panel-data-label">
          Effective Date
        </div>
        <div class="panel-data-value">
          1 Jan 2018
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-data panel-data-vertical">
        <div class="panel-data-label">
          Employment Type
        </div>
        <div class="panel-data-value">
          Permanent
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-data panel-data-vertical">
        <div class="panel-data-label">
          Job Level
        </div>
        <div class="panel-data-value">
          Staff
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-data panel-data-vertical">
        <div class="panel-data-label">
          Job Title
        </div>
        <div class="panel-data-value">
          All
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-2">
      
    </div>
    <div class="col-3">
      
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! But how can I put a distance between the side of card to the line? I attach image on my question if you want to check it..

Comment: i had made some changes, is that you needed?

Comment: I mean the line isn't 100% the card's width like the picture on my question.. is there any way to solve it?

Comment: check is it okay for you

Comment: check now, it was written in table, so issues might come if we change it